# Optimizing an union SQL query

Tags: mysql, pdo, query-optimization, union

I've got a big query that all contain same types I need for a feed that I list in my app. Now the problem is that this query isn't very fast. I'm thinking that if I limit each individual union it might speed it up a bit but I'm not sure.

So basically my question is how could I optimize this query to execute faster?

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
      alert_id, 
      uniquekey, 
      type, 
      user_id, 
      date_added 
   FROM 
   (
     ( SELECT 
             r.alert_id, 
             r.alert_id AS uniquekey, 
             'reply' AS `type`,
             r.user_id, 
             r.date_added
          FROM 
             `reply` r 
                LEFT JOIN `alerts` a
                   ON r.alert_id = a.alert_content_id  
          WHERE 
                 r.user_id = :id 
             AND a.hide = '0'
          ORDER BY 
             date_added DESC )
     UNION
     ( SELECT 
             r.alert_id, 
             r.alert_id AS uniquekey, 
             'replyfromfollowing' AS `type`,
             r.user_id, 
             r.date_added
          FROM 
             `reply` r 
                LEFT JOIN `alerts` a
                   ON r.alert_id = a.alert_content_id 
          WHERE 
                 r.user_id IN( '$followingstring' ) 
             AND a.hide = '0'
            ORDER BY date_added DESC )
     UNION 
     ( SELECT 
             i.alert_id, 
             i.alert_id AS uniquekey, 
             'liked' AS `type`,
             i.user_id, 
             i.date_added 
          FROM 
             `interactions` i 
                LEFT JOIN `alerts` a
                   ON i.alert_id = a.alert_content_id 
          WHERE 
                 i.user_id = :id 
             AND a.hide = '0'
          GROUP BY 
             alert_id
          ORDER BY 
             date_added DESC )
     UNION 
     ( SELECT 
             i.alert_id, 
             i.alert_id AS uniquekey, 
             'likedfromfollowing' AS `type`,
             i.user_id, 
             i.date_added 
          FROM 
             `interactions` i 
                LEFT JOIN `alerts` a
                   ON i.alert_id = a.alert_content_id
          WHERE 
                 i.user_id IN ( '$followingstring' ) 
             AND a.hide = '0'
          GROUP BY 
             alert_id
          ORDER BY 
             date_added DESC ) 
     UNION 
     ( SELECT 
             alerts as alert_id,
             alert_content_id AS uniquekey,
             'following' AS `type`,
             user_id, 
             date_added 
          FROM 
             alerts a 
                LEFT JOIN `alerts_content` ac 
                   ON ac.id = a.alert_content_id 
          WHERE 
                 a.user_id IN ( '$followingstring' ) 
             AND ac.anoniem = '0' 
             AND a.hide = '0' 
          GROUP BY 
             alert_id 
          ORDER BY 
             date_added DESC )
      ) joined 
   GROUP BY 
      uniquekey 
   ORDER BY 
      date_added DESC 
   LIMIT 
      ".(int)$start.",20"
```

table structures

```
Reply table Structure:
id
user_id
alert_id
description
reply_on_alert
reply_on_reply
date_added

Interaction table Structure:
id
alert_id
action_id
reply_id
user_id
date_added

Alerts table structure(Yes i know BIG mistake naming `id` : `alerts`):
alerts
title
alert_content_id
user_id
cat
lat
lon
state
hide
date_added

alerts_content table structure:
id
alert_id
description
img
```

results of query:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [alert_id] => 173404
            [uniquekey] => 173404
            [type] => reply
            [user_id] => 2
            [date_added] => 2015-06-01 16:34:16
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [alert_id] => 172174
            [uniquekey] => 172174
            [type] => replyfromfollowing
            [user_id] => 1380
            [date_added] => 2015-06-01 16:01:04
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [alert_id] => 171772
            [uniquekey] => 171772
            [type] => liked
            [user_id] => 2
            [date_added] => 2015-06-01 15:58:44
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [alert_id] => 149423
            [uniquekey] => 149423
            [type] => reply
            [user_id] => 2
            [date_added] => 2015-06-01 15:25:56
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [alert_id] => 164742
            [uniquekey] => 164742
            [type] => reply
            [user_id] => 2
            [date_added] => 2015-05-12 09:46:39
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [alert_id] => 163344
            [uniquekey] => 163344
            [type] => replyfromfollowing
            [user_id] => 3
            [date_added] => 2015-05-12 09:44:46
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [alert_id] => 164205
            [uniquekey] => 164205
            [type] => liked
            [user_id] => 2
            [date_added] => 2015-05-11 11:06:39
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [alert_id] => 160890
            [uniquekey] => 160890
            [type] => replyfromfollowing
            [user_id] => 1380
            [date_added] => 2015-05-08 14:29:34
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [alert_id] => 163002
            [uniquekey] => 163002
            [type] => replyfromfollowing
            [user_id] => 1380
            [date_added] => 2015-05-08 13:31:12
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [alert_id] => 159123
            [uniquekey] => 159123
            [type] => replyfromfollowing
            [user_id] => 48
            [date_added] => 2015-04-30 15:10:32
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [alert_id] => 150546
            [uniquekey] => 150546
            [type] => replyfromfollowing
            [user_id] => 16
            [date_added] => 2015-04-21 21:52:49
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [alert_id] => 149497
            [uniquekey] => 149497
            [type] => reply
            [user_id] => 2
            [date_added] => 2015-04-10 15:19:06
        )

    [12] => Array
        (
            [alert_id] => 141078
            [uniquekey] => 141078
            [type] => liked
            [user_id] => 2
            [date_added] => 2015-04-10 15:15:32
        )

    [13] => Array
        (
            [alert_id] => 125466
            [uniquekey] => 125466
            [type] => replyfromfollowing
            [user_id] => 3
            [date_added] => 2015-04-09 00:15:22
        )

    [14] => Array
        (
            [alert_id] => 134592
            [uniquekey] => 134592
            [type] => replyfromfollowing
            [user_id] => 3
            [date_added] => 2015-04-09 00:11:04
        )

    [15] => Array
        (
            [alert_id] => 124194
            [uniquekey] => 124194
            [type] => likedfromfollowing
            [user_id] => 3
            [date_added] => 2015-04-09 00:08:35
        )

    [16] => Array
        (
            [alert_id] => 128645
            [uniquekey] => 128645
            [type] => likedfromfollowing
            [user_id] => 3
            [date_added] => 2015-04-09 00:07:29
        )

    [17] => Array
        (
            [alert_id] => 144867
            [uniquekey] => 144867
            [type] => replyfromfollowing
            [user_id] => 3
            [date_added] => 2015-04-06 13:59:19
        )

    [18] => Array
        (
            [alert_id] => 133355
            [uniquekey] => 133355
            [type] => liked
            [user_id] => 2
            [date_added] => 2015-03-31 16:16:15
        )

    [19] => Array
        (
            [alert_id] => 141075
            [uniquekey] => 141075
            [type] => liked
            [user_id] => 2
            [date_added] => 2015-03-30 15:17:01
        )

)
```

Comment: Use EXPLAIN, you can see where you should add indexes to tables so that the statement executes faster by using indexes to find rows. - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/explain.html

Comment: can't you post structure and some sample data

Comment: Run all the subqueries separately to find out if there is one in particular that is slow. Also, using `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION` can improve performance but it could also change the results since it allows duplicates in the result set.

Comment: union all improved it a bit. i select distinct and group before the unions so the dupes aren't a problem. query still takes around 8 seconds though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some possibilities, in no particular order:

**Optimization #1:**

Use `LIMIT` in the subqueries, too.  However, since you are using `OFFSET`, it may not be obvious how to do it.

Before the query, calculate $start+20 and put it into, say, $limit.  Then use `LIMIT $limit` for the inner queries.  No, don't use an `OFFSET` on them.  This guarantees that you get enough rows from each query to satisfy the outer `OFFSET $start LIMIT 20`.

**Optimization #2:**

Restructure the tables so that you don't need to `JOIN` to another table (`alerts`) to find out whether to show the record.  That is, having `hide` prevents a number of potential optimizations.  Before advising further, we need to understand the need for `LEFT`.  Are there rows in `reply`, etc, that are not in `alerts`?  If not, get rid of the `LEFT` and look into searching `alerts with the`OFFSET`and`LIMIT`, then joining to the 4 other tables.

**Optimization #3:**

Restructure the data so that there is *one* core table, with `alerts` and the 4 other tables hanging off it.  Be sure to have most (all?) of the fields needed for *this* query in this new table.

**Optimization #4:**

The current structure requires the full scan of each of the 4 tables before even thinking about `OFFSET` and `LIMIT`.  This smells like "pagination"; is it?  For optimizing "pagination", the goals are to avoid the table scan and `OFFSET`; instead remember where you "left off" so that the query can be

```
WHERE ... AND x < $left_off
ORDER by x DESC
LIMIT 20
```

This should make it possible to read only 20 rows, not the entire table(s).  That would make the query *much* faster, especially for later pages.  (A bigger `OFFSET` costs more time`)

I discuss pagination optimization in [my blog](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pagination).

Comment: nice and detailed explanation about possible optimizations, the restructure isn't possible due to it being an app and earlier versions will have to be supported in the future :(